# Does liquid smoke differ in intensity from brand to brand and if yes, how to compensate?

Tags: smoke-flavor

Does the intensity of the flavor of liquid smoke differ significantly from brand to brand?

If yes, suppose I'm following a recipe that calls for a certain amount of liquid smoke. If the brand I'm using is different from theirs, the results could be wildly different. Is there any good method to compensate for any such differences other than just to try and see?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I have seen gigantic differences in potency. There’s not much you can do about this; if possible, try to use the same brand as the recipe refers to. A saving grace is that liquid smoke doesn’t need to be cooked to release its flavor, so you can be conservative when adding it initially and then add more near the end if you think more smokiness is needed.